# Does a startup need a separate CEO?

Tags: startup, equity

I am the technical founder of a startup in seed phase. I will probably do all software development (except of graphical design) by myself.

The startup is an innovative social network on blockchain.

I was told that I need to "hire" a CEO, not to be a sole entrepreneur, who are usually not funded by VCs.

So, do I need to hire a CEO?

If I hire a CEO, how much equity should I give to the CEO? If I have more then I can override his/her decisions, so he/she would be not a real CEO, wouldn't he/she?

So, should I give more equity to CEO then to myself? Or give him/her more voting rights that to myself, but without much equity (percent paid)?

Comment: who told you this? was it a VC? or was it somebody else?

Comment: Ask yourself, do you have the time to do the work a CEO does? Or can your time be better devoted to working on the technical aspects?

Comment: You are asking the question from the wrong side. The real question is what am I missing to achieve my mission, and how to solve it. The answer then may be CEO, and rest falls into place. That's really business 101, i highly recommend some minimal courses in it asap or you will learn all of them the hard and expensive way.

Comment: Not really a workplace question, more of a business question.

Comment: Being a "solentrepreneur" suggests that you are trying to do nearly everything yourself. A social network is quite the opposite. A distributed social network using blockchain is so much on the other side that I would wonder how you could pull this off yourself. Are you sure that the message is "hire a CEO" or could it really be "build up a team including a CEO?"

Comment: Isnt this for you to decide.  What do you want ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need to?  No.  May it bring you value?  Yes.  It's all dependent on how well you can do the job, and whether you can convince an investor of that.  It frequently helps a founder because the set of  skills needed to create a technology and the skills needed to do the business side of a company are not frequently held by the same person.  They can be, but its also common for a technical person and a business person to pair up.  As for how much equity to give-  what's the smallest amount the person you want to hire will accept?  That's the proper amount.  There isn't a magic formula.

Comment: All that said, I think "social network on a blockchain" is a bigger blocker than the lack of a CEO.  Blockchain alone is a red flag in most circles these days, and I see no value in adding one to a social network.

Comment: But this one's innovative.

Comment: Says every blockchain project ever

Comment: It is not. It is 2 not exactly super rare concepts put together in a way that is having what benefit exactly? What is the business model? I would not put my money into it. Not today.

Answer (score 10):

You miss the point - brutally. It is not (only) about having a CEO, it is about having a SECOND PERSON. Single entrepreneurs are generally hard to get funding for because it is high risk. Anything happens, the ONE person that knew how the company ran is now in coma and the investment garbage. With a second person at least, there is a paper trail of what is to be done that he can use to hire someone else to go on.
This is about the bus factor if you need outside investment.
So, it is not about what YOU need - this is irrelevant. Want investor funds (VC) - well, their money, their rules. And a Bus Factor of one IS a red flag.

Comment: Just realize - that will look retarded in a quarter latest. It is true - but it totally ignores that within the year we can likely have in most startups most functions done by AI. Just had a meeting yesterday with my PR and Marketing leads and both of them are not human. And yes, that is "meeting" as in "chatting in one room with each other hammering out a strategy". This will not age well - maybe a #2 and #3, but the next large company may well stop human headcount there.

Answer (score -1):

Although a business person plus a technical person makes sense the real issue is your whole team.

It may be that you can be the CEO and get a marketing person, for example. Even a second strong tech person will keep you from being seen as a one-person-band.

A CEO can be fired by the board. As the founder you might be a board member and also an employee. As an employee you dork for the CEO; as a board member you have a say in the company’s goals and direction including the choice of CEO.

When the founders of Google hired Eric Schmidt they gave him significant stock-based incentives but not more ownership then they had.

Comment: Missing the point - a marketing person will not convince a VC that the bus factor is larger than 1.

Comment: “bus factor” a typo ?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite [Bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor).

Comment: @gidds - thanks. I think VCs are looking for super stars backed up by a core team and that succession planning is for a later stage.

Comment: Nope. The bus factor is not the classical succession planning - it is for basically me giving some smart guy a million and then the smart guy crosses the street and gets hit by a bus. Million is pretty much toast. THAT is the bus factor. Succession is about stepping aside and inheritance - this is about business continuity.

Comment: @TomTom - actual succession can happen for many reasons -  bus, better offer, death, disability. If that is not the right word in your few, fine. My point is that succession and/or business continuity is not high on a VC checklist. They want one or a couple of super-star founders backed up by a good team and it is not important or likely that a team member is an invest-able substitute for the super-stars. The time frame to VC exit is short compared to the frequency of bus accidents.